# Google Sitie Buscar texto en mi página que no está dentro de un Cuadro de texto con el buscador de Google Sitie

Tags: google-sites

cuando inserto un formulario, una página de Google sheets el contenido que contienen no se puede buscar desde el buscador de Google Sitie, no encuentra la búsqueda, sólo encuentra el contenido de Google Sitie de mi página si está escrita directamente dentro de de un Cuadro de texto de Google Sitie, que solución podrí obtener para poder buscar dentro del contenido de las cosas insertadas o incrustados en mi página.

Por ejemplo:

inserto una página de Google Sheets con nombres y celulares de clientes en mi página de Google Sitie y quiero buscar el nombre de uno específico desde el buscador de Google Sitie y no lo encuentra y sé que está ahí, que está escrito correctamente...... Ayuda por favor, gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: El buscador de google site donde hice una web quiero que me encuentre el texto que traigo de otra página web y no lo hace, solamente encuentra textos que inserto en un cuadro de textos de google site y necesito hacer busquedas de textos dentro de los elementos incrustados en mis páginas de google site como google formulario, google sheets

Comment: ¿Haz consultado la documentación del servicio de Google que estás usando? Por otro lado, te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Si tu pregunta está enfocada a saber cómo funciona o cómo se utiliza el buscador de Google Site, entonces tu pregunta no es relavante a [es.so], tal como establece el [help/on-topic]